# Forces to move a mass up and down and relation to potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, work

Basically the question is: Does it take the same forces to move a mass up or down including acceleration and deceleration?

The Newton second law: $F=m*a$ tend to say yes. In reality this is far from the case. Is it only due to friction? Is it also due to the increase of potential energy when moving a mass up: $E=F*Height$? I cannot find anywhere any relation between the increase or decrease of potential energy and the forces necessary to move an object.

Practical example for those interested where we have a motor moving a mass up and down using rack and pinion and where we measure the motor torque:

We need to move a mass $m=650kg$ up and down vertically with a target velocity of $1 m/s$ and are using acceleration and deceleration of $1m/s^2$

The necessary forces during acceleration upward should be $F=m*(g+acc)= 650 * (9.8 + 1)=7000N$  in reality we measure them be around 8300N

Accelerating downward should be $F=650 * (9.8 -1)=5700N$ , we measure 3000N

During move both upward and downward at constant velocity and staying still without friction the necessary forces should be $F=m*g = 650*9.8 = 6300N$ but we measure they are around 5200N standing still, 7000N moving up  and 5300N moving down.

We could explain the difference by considering we have around 1000N friction. It is possible, but then where do the increase in potential energy comes from?

Update: explain setup and how we measure forces.
Update 2: precise the velcoty is not constant during entire move. It is just a target velocity

Comment: "We need to move a mass $m=650kg$ up and down vertically at $1 m/s$ and acceleration of $1m/s^2$" which is it, a constant velocity of 1 m/s or an acceleration of 1 m/s$^2$? I find this and other statements you make difficult to follow.

Comment: You can apply constant force/acceleration OR constant velocity but not both at the same time (unless the acceleration is zero).

Comment: I have tried to make the description clearer. We are doing move up and down, so they have an acceleration and decceleration phases and a long phase with constant velocity

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your testing setup. If you could provide details about how your measurements have been done, then we might find the cause

Comment: Note:  the word *deceleration* is not defined in physics.   Does it mean *slowing down*, or does it mean *negative acceleration*?   An object executing negative acceleration in the negative direction is speeding up.  It's best to never use the word *decelerate*.

Comment: @Garyp A pedant would argue that acceleration is a vector and has a direction rather than a sign. It is *components* of acceleration (having decided on a co-ordinate system) that can be positive or negative.

Comment: Can I know why exactly the question is closed? I got the answers I needed, so I am fine, but just out of curiosity, I am wondering what detail is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a simple example: A mass of $1kg$. For simplicity we make the gravitational acceleration $g = 10m/s^2$

Let's apply a force of $F = 20N$ over a time of $t_1 = 1s$. The net acceleration will be $a_1 = F/m-g = 10m/s^2$. Let's look at the state of affair after one second. The velocity of the objects will be

$$v_1 = a_1 t_1 = 10m/s$$

The position will be

$$ x_1 = \frac{1}{2} a_1t_1^2 = 5m$$

Let's look at energies: the potential energy is

$$E_{pot1} = x_1g = 50 J$$

The energy that we have expended is

$$E_0 = x_1F = 100J $$

So where is the rest? The object is moving at $10m/s$ so it has kinetic energy as well, so we have

$$E_{kin1} = \frac{1}{2}mv_1^2 = 50J$$

And it all works out: the energy we have put in has been conserved and it's split between kinetic and potential energy of the object. If we stop the acceleration the object will still keep going since it has momentum. Now the only force acting on it is gravity so the net acceleration is now $a_2 = -10m/s^2$

By a simple symmetry argument, the object will come to a halt at $t = 2s$ at a height of $x_2 = 10m$ a and speed of $v_2 = 0$. The kinetic energy is 0 but the potential energy is now

$$E_{pot2} = x_2g = 100J$$

And again the energy is fully balanced. We can continue the tracking the object: At $t=3s$ the object is back down halfway: $x_3 = 50m$, $v_3 = -10m/s$ and we have the same energy balance then we have at $t=1s$.

The object will reach it's original location ($x4 = 0$) at

$$t_4 = t_2 + \sqrt{2(x_4-x_2)/a_2} = 2s + \sqrt{2}s$$

At this point the velocity is

$$v_4 = a_2(t4-t2) = 10\sqrt{2}m/s$$

and the kinetic energy is

$$E_{kin4} = \frac{1}{2}mv_4^2 = 100J = E_0$$

Now all the input energy has been turned into kinetic Energy of the object.

Comment: All answers were correct, but you were the most precise so I flagged that one as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that giving something potential energy somehow 'consumes' force. But this is not the case. A 650 kg body will require an upward force of 6.38 kN (equal and opposite to the pull of gravity of 6.38 kN) in order to move upward at constant speed (having first been set in motion). As it moves upwards it will acquire 6.38 kJ of gravitational potential energy for each 1.00 m of upward motion. This is the amount of *work* done per metre by the lifting force. No extra force is needed to give the potential energy. Acquiring gravitational potential energy is part and parcel of being moved upwards in the Earth's gravitational field.

Extra force would, though, be needed to give the body an upward *acceleration*. An extra 650 N for each increment of 1.00 m s$^{-2}$. [An extra force of 650 N would result in a gain in *kinetic* energy of 650 J per metre of motion. This is in addition to the gain in gravitational potential energy.]

When you say "in reality" these forces are [the values that you give], I'm assuming that they have been measured. Friction is indeed the only simple way of accounting for the discrepancy between calculated and measured values.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Yes we measure the forces (or moment from motors). Intuitively I have issues accepting that the increase of potential does not "consume forces" but you are most probably right and will try to read a bit more on that subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will require the same force to accelerate the mass just as much regardless of direction of motion because mass - the "resistance" against motion - is directionless.

If sounds like you specifically are asking to your own applied force, though. And then the answer is obviously no. Because, obviously, if other forces are present along some directions and not along other directions, then they will help our or resist further the effect of your applied force.

Such other forces could be e.g. the gravitational force or friction. The increase in potential energy that you mention is another word of saying that gravity counteracts your force, thus making it tougher for you to lift the object.

> I cannot find anywhere any relation between the increase or decrease of potential energy and the forces necessary to move an object.

An equation relating energy with forces is the work formula:

$$W=\int F\cdot \mathrm dx\approx F\,\Delta x.$$

Each influencing force does work on the object being moved. All energy changes, potential, kinetic or other, are due to such work being done.

> Practical example from work for those interested

(In your question phrasing you mention a speed of 1 m/s that can't be correct since the speed can't be constant. But it also isn't involved in your calculation, so no bother.)

I agree with your calculation here. If you measure something else than the calculated amount of exerted force, then look for sources of error. Yes, friction might be one. Depending on object shape, air drag might be one. And the largest factor may be your method of measuring the value - is it done via delicate equipment, or with a manual, handheld Newtonmeter that might not have been held entirely still all the way through?

If you could provide details about how your measurements have been done, then it might be easier to figure out why your unexpectedly different values are showing up.

Comment: Thanks. I update the description to to precise how we measure the forces. It is a vertical rack and pinion setup with a motor moving a mass vertically. I do not think we need to look any further than friction in the  rails and gear to explain the difference. the only other potential suspect could have been if increase in potental energy somehow consumed energy but it seems from your answer that it does not